# Is the use of Struct or Class personal preference?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, classes

I have a solution in which I instantiate a class with various types inside of it.  I feel it is becoming to cumbersome to instantiate and then create  variables for each of the types I want to access in the class (Option 2 in the code), so I've come up with a custom return type so I only have to return data once for use (option 1).

So with the struct my code is more readible in the MAIN block, but is there a better way to do this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace retclass
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //Option 1 Struct and function
            //create struct
            ret x = new ret();
            x = goofie(3, "this is the struct string");
            Console.WriteLine("The String is {0}, the int is {1} and the value is {2}", x.str, x.num, x.yesno);


            //Option 2 Class
            //Instantiate retclass
            retclass retins = new retclass();
            retins.num = 3;
            retins.str = "this is the class string";
            if ((retins.num > 0) && retins.str != "")
            {
                retins.yesno = true;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("The String is {0}, the int is {1} and the value is {2}", retins.str, retins.num, retins.yesno);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }

        public struct ret
        {
            public int num { get; set; }
            public string str { get; set; }
            public bool yesno { get; set; }
        }        

        public static ret goofie(int isn, string ss)
        {
            ret dex = new ret();
            dex.str = ss;
            dex.num = isn;
            if ((dex.str != "") && (dex.num > 0))
            {
                dex.yesno = true;
            }
            return dex;
        }
    }

    public class retclass
    {
        public int num { get; set; }
        public string str { get; set; }
        public bool yesno { get; set; }
    }   

}
```

Comment: For immutable types its mostly a performance choice depending on the size of the class/struct. For mutable types, go with the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [`MSDN Page`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017.aspx) states:

> **CONSIDER** defining a struct instead of a class
>
> - if instances of the type are small and commonly short-lived or are commonly embedded in other objects.
>
> **AVOID** defining a struct unless the type has all of the following characteristics:
>
> - It logically represents a single value, similar to primitive types (int, double, etc.).
> - It has an instance size under 16 bytes.
> - It is immutable.
> - It will not have to be boxed frequently.

So if you want to use a class instead of a structure, you can just add the same static `goofy` method, to get the same `style` like you get with the structure:

```
   public static retclass goofie(int isn, string ss)
    {
        retclass dex = new retclass();
        dex.str = ss;
        dex.num = isn;
        if ((dex.str != "") && (dex.num > 0))
        {
            dex.yesno = true;
        }
        return dex;
    }
```

You can either add this to the `Main` or better inside the class itself. If you consider the second, you can call it like:

```
retclass x = retclass.goofie(3, "this is the reclass string");

Console.WriteLine("The String is {0}, the int is {1} and the value 
      is {2}", x.str, x.num, x.yesno);
```

Comment: Thanks, that does make it a bit more readable.  I like the way it is called.

Answer (score 2):

A structure can be used when you want a type that represents a single entity. A structure is more complicated to implement correctly, so unless there is any special reason, just stick to classes.

You dont need to make it a struct to get a conventient way to create it. Make the constructor take the values.

The `YesNo` property doesn't even need to be stored in the type. Just calculate it when needed.

```
public class ReturnValue {

    public int Num { get; private set; }
    public string Str { get; private set; }

    public bool YesNo { get { return Str != "" && Num > 0; } }

    public ReturnValue(int num, string str) {
      Num = num;
      Str = str;
    }

}
```